# Maven dependency exclusions: Same artifact-id issue

Tags: apache, maven, apache-fop

I have an Apache Cocoon Project and I wanted to update Apache FOP from 1.0 to 1.1, in order to fix foreign (non-latin) script issues, such as Greek.

I found FOP 1.1 has a Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
  <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**ERROR:** *Failed to execute goal on project X: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.X:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: **Failure to find org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.2.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2** was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]*

I search for a solution in this issue and I found that this dependency has broken links to some other dependencies, which FOP 1.1 needs to call. These are connected with Avalon framework API 4.2. I read in a mailing list that maybe trying to use exclusions and call extra dependencies is working fine. The solution was this code:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
  <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <!-- these two are to correct issues in fop dependency --> 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
   <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
   <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now compilation returns the following **ERROR2:** *"Failed to execute goal org.apache.cocoon:cocoon-maven-plugin:1.0.0-M2:prepare (prepare) on project X: **There are at least two artifacts with the ID 'avalon-framework-api'**: avalon-framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.2.0:compile".*

Of course there are. Two dependencies are excluded, the broken ones, and two of them are called, the correct ones. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is there a mechanism to request that either FOP 1.1 be removed from the maven central repo, or that the missing artifacts get added? Seems strange that things have been allowed to get into this broken state.

Answer (score 9):

Haven't tested this yet, but perhaps excluding org.apache.avalon.framework v4.2.0 and include the latest v4.3.1 instead.  Such as:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```